# Ubuntu in Virtual Box

Tags: system-installation, virtualbox

I have just tried to install Ubuntu on Virtual Box machine using [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sB_5fqiysi4). It all works perfectly fine up to 10:42 seconds. However, when I click "restart now", I get the message

> Please remove the installation medium, and press ENTER

I don't know what the message "Please remove the installation medium, and press ENTER" refers to.

I am doing a Virtual Box installation. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The installer is simply telling you to remove the `.iso` file you mounted to the virtual machine as a virtual CD/DVD or USB drive. It tells you to do this so that when it reboots to complete the installation, your machine does not boot into the installation media, but rather, your newly installed OS on the virtual hard drive.

To complete what it is asking you, unmount the Ubuntu `.iso` file you mounted at the beginning. Virtual box may even disconnect it for you after you reboot. From the virtual box setting bar, the navigation would look like:

*Devices → CD/DVD Devices → Remove disk from virtual drive*